# Alexa access token ivalid scope

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

Im traing to build my own Alexa skill to send message from Python to power on/off devices.
Im reading the official documentation (https://developer.amazon.com/it-IT/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html) but I cant retrieve the token because i have the invalid scope.
I will attach configurations screen
[Account linking configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFgvj.png)
The code is

```
import requests

SKILL_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxx'
SKILL_CLIENT_ID = 'amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxx'
SKILL_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
API_TOKEN_URL = 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token'


def richiediToken():
    scope = "alexa:skill_messaging"
    payload = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=" + scope + "&client_id=" + \
        SKILL_CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + SKILL_CLIENT_SECRET
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    print("Header: ", headers)
    print("Body: ", payload)
    richiestaToken = requests.post(
        API_TOKEN_URL, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print("Risposta:")
    print(richiestaToken.json())


richiediToken()
```

Why the scope provided by documentation doesn't works??
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a wrong secret. According to [doc](https://developer.amazon.com/it-IT/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html) you have linked, you should obtain it from Permissions section:

> 1. Open the skills list in the developer console, and click Edit for your skill.
>    2. On the Build tab, click the **Permissions** section on the bottom left.
>    3. Scroll to the Alexa Skill Messaging section at the bottom of the Permissions page.
>    4. Copy the Client Id and Client Secret values for later use.

According to the screen you've shared - you are using values from **Account Linking** tab.

Your code works correctly with clientId/secret from Permissions tab:

```sh
λ docker run so-python
Header:  {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
Body:  grant_type=client_credentials&scope=alexa:skill_messaging&client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.(...)&client_secret=(...)
Risposta:
{'access_token': 'Atc|MQEBI(...)', 'scope': 'alexa:skill_messaging', 'token_type': 'bearer', 'expires_in': 3600}
```

Later on to send the message:

```py
    token = richiestaToken.json()
    authorization = "Bearer " + list(token.values())[0] + ""
    print(authorization)
    messagePayload= {"data": {"sampleMessage": "Sample Message"}, "expiresAfterSeconds": 60}
    messageHeaders = {'Authorization': authorization, 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    messageResponse = requests.post(
        "https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skillmessages/users/amzn1.ask.account.AG4SB7...",
        json=messagePayload,
        headers=messageHeaders
        )
    print(messageResponse)
```

It should return 202 HTTP status.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
In the permisison section I haven't skill messaging section....
I have to enable it? If yes, how?

Comment: " Note: If you do not see the Alexa Skill Messaging section, then toggle a permission on the page. The Alexa Skill Messaging section then appears. Once you have copied Client Id and Client Secret values, you can then change the permission back if you want.”, https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html

Comment: Thank u. I have clientid and clientsecret but still not working because of scope. I need to set the scope in the skill configuration? The guide doesn't say this...

Comment: You declare the scope you want to use in request body. The question is - which api you want to call later on using obtained access_token?

Comment: I'm using the doc linked before. I'd like to call _https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token_ for the token and after _api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v1/skillmessages/users/{userId}_ for the skill. The doc says to use the first link to retrieve the token before to use the sencond link. What's my fault?

Comment: Try US endpoint - api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skillmessages/users/{userId}

I edited the response and added the code for sending the message - works on my machine :)

Comment: I don't know why my code works on your machine. I have problem with the scope when I try to retrieve the token... Maybe I have some options not configured... I don't know what I have to configure to retrieve the token...
My permission page (https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3637/celmtA.png). I have omitted the clientid and clientsecret.
My account linking page (https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/279/5h6sKj.png). All disabled.
Something wrong?